# Removing an item from a (multidimensional) list in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to remove an item from a list, the code looks like:

```
s = []
full_c = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']

for i in range(5):
    s.append(full_c)

try:
    s[2].remove('1')
except:
    pass

print(*s,sep="\n")
```

Here I intend to remove the item '1' from the third row alone.

The result is:

```
['0', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
['0', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
['0', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
['0', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
['0', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
```

Why the specific item is removed from every list (within the main list)? How to remove only one entry from the third row alone?

Comment: You're appending the same list five times. See linked dupe.

Comment: You can check my question to find answer on yours: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27475539/creating-and-working-with-list-of-lists-of-lists-in-python

Comment: instead of `.append(full_c)` do `.append(full_c[:])`

Comment: Thank you all. @DavidZemens, it works they way I wanted.